# What FPS is this GIF from?

Tags: game-identification

What's the game in this GIF?

[image]

(FPS where some guys run through a door without opening, then one runs back and kicks open the door so the last guy can get through.)

Comment: Looks like BF3... with some "ghost" recon.

Comment: Looks like one of the Rainbow Six games, but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That appears to be Battlefield 3. Looks like the mission Operation Guillotine.

You'll see that scene in the very beginning of this video.